# Can not build CMake Project

Tags: c, cmake, build

I am trying to install deltachat as described here:
https://github.com/deltachat/deltachat-core-rust#installing-libdeltachat-system-wide

But when i try to execut, i always get this error.

```
cmake --build build
Microsoft (R)-Build-Engine, Version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 für .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.


  Generating target/release/libdeltachat.a, target/release/libdeltachat.so, target/release/pkgconfig/deltachat.pc
  The command "PREFIX" is either misspelled or
  could not be found.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(209,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" wurde mit dem Code 9009 beendet.
```

What could be the Problem here?

Comment: How have you configured the project? The command `cmake -B build . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr` is suitable for Linux, but not for Windows.

Comment: .so files on windows? Unless you were setting up cross compilation, this is not the correct file extension of a shared libary...

Comment: Btw: the command in the CMakeLists.txt file simply doesn't work on the windows command line ( https://github.com/deltachat/deltachat-core-rust/blob/ddefd2cf09a406768c6581397d5a64ac693b018f/CMakeLists.txt#L12) You may be able to rewrite the command in a semi-system-independent manner by using a cmake script executed via the command of `add_custom_command` though and use `set(ENV{PREFIX} ...)`ect. to set the environment for the cargo tool invokation. Unless you're modifying the sources though, I'd recommend simply building&installing the lib via cargo and creating a cmake imported library target